# User Contact List and Lync

Tags: list, user-profile, active-directory, contacts

I am struggling in creating a contact list.
Our company requires a sharepoint contact list so that the details of AD users are shown.
It would be great if the online status of users is shown.
I think for this, I have to start user profile synchronization service.
But there is a condition.
The contact list should allow Lync calls to the user by clicking the user in contact list.
I cannot find any related articles or blogs for this purpose.

Thanks

Asado

Answer (score 1):

Presence in SharePoint is enabled when the user has a valid SIP address associated with their User Profile. The visitor has to have an IM client like Lync, IM or Communicator, and they have to be logged in to the messaging server.

When you say you have to "create a contact list". What do you mean? If you enable profile import, the User Profile Service will maintain all the active users in the User Profiles. Crawl this with search and you have a significantly more powerful synchronized service. Maintaining a static list will be burden.

Comment: Hi Mathew,
"Create a contact list" means to create a list that stores profile information of all active AD users so that the users can find info about others just by clicking that list, rather than going through the search.

Now, after user profile synchronization service, is there any method to populate a contact list with users in User Profiles? And this list gets updated with the update to User Profiles?

Comment: I would not use a list as you now have two synchronizations to manage. I would use a static query against the People scope that returns all people in the company.